# Problems with a simulation study of the repeated experiments explanation of a 95% confidence interval - where am I going wrong?

Tags: r, confidence-interval, binomial-distribution, mathematical-statistics

I'm trying to write an R script to simulate the repeated experiments interpretation of a 95% confidence interval. I've found that it overestimates the proportion of times in which the true population value of a proportion is contained within the sample's 95% CI.  Not a big difference - about 96% vs 95% but this interested me nonetheless.

My function takes a sample `samp_n` from a Bernoulli distribution with probability `pop_p`, and then calculates a 95% confidence interval with `prop.test()` using continuity correction, or more exactly with `binom.test()`.  It returns 1 if the true population proportion `pop_p` is contained within the 95% CI.  I've written two functions, one which uses `prop.test()` and one which uses `binom.test()` and have had similar results with both:

```
in_conf_int_normal <- function(pop_p = 0.3, samp_n = 1000, correct = T){
    ## uses normal approximation to calculate confidence interval
    ## returns 1 if the CI contain the pop proportion
    ## returns 0 otherwise
    samp <- rbinom(samp_n, 1, pop_p)
    pt_result <- prop.test(length(which(samp == 1)), samp_n)
    lb <- pt_result$conf.int[1]
        ub <- pt_result$conf.int[2]
    if(pop_p < ub & pop_p > lb){
        return(1)
    } else {
    return(0)
    }
}
in_conf_int_binom <- function(pop_p = 0.3, samp_n = 1000, correct = T){
    ## uses Clopper and Pearson method
    ## returns 1 if the CI contain the pop proportion
    ## returns 0 otherwise
    samp <- rbinom(samp_n, 1, pop_p)
    pt_result <- binom.test(length(which(samp == 1)), samp_n)
    lb <- pt_result$conf.int[1]
        ub <- pt_result$conf.int[2] 
    if(pop_p < ub & pop_p > lb){
        return(1)
    } else {
    return(0)
    }
 }
```

I've found that when you repeat the experiment a few thousand times, the proportion of times when the `pop_p` is within the 95% CI of the sample is closer to 0.96 rather than 0.95.

```
set.seed(1234)
times = 10000
results <- replicate(times, in_conf_int_binom())
sum(results) / times
[1] 0.9562
```

My thoughts so far about why this may be the case are

- my code is wrong (but I've checked it a lot)
- I initially thought that this was due to the normal approximation issue, but then found `binom.test()`

Any suggestions?

Comment: (+1) By the way, I re-ran your code with `times=100000` a few different times and saw the same result. I'm curious to see if anyone has an explanation for this. The code is sufficiently simple that I'm pretty certain there is no coding error. Also, one run with `times=1000000` gave `.954931` as the result.

Comment: (+1) But why do you expect to get exactly 95%? Clopper Pearson for example is guaranteed to be conservative. For your $n$ and $p$, I get that the CI should cover the true value 95.3648% of the time.

Comment: Here's what I get with sample sizes of (100, 300, 1000, 3000, 10,000) and 100,000 replications: (0.96363 0.95638 0.95486 0.95076 0.95086).  Based on this, and @cardinal 's  comment (+1), (I didn't do the arithmetic as he did), I'm not seeing an asymptotic problem.

Comment: Correction: For CP it should yield 95.4609% and for the normal test it should yield 95.0857% coverage. (Previous calculation was off due to a zero-indexing error.)

Comment: To support cardinals comment exact binomial probabilities are exact because the are based on an exact probability calculation but they do not necessarily give the exact confidence level.  That is because the binomial is a discrete distribution.  So Clopper-Pearson picks the endpoint for the interval so that you have the closest probability to the confidence level at or above it.  This also creates a sawtoothed behavior to the power function of an exact binomial test.  This odd but basic result is discussed in my paper with Christine Liu in the American Statistician (2002).

Comment: Details on my paper at this link:  http://www.citeulike.org/user/austin987/article/7571878

Comment: Exact Binomial CIs are "exact" because their actual performance equals their nominal performance, not because the probability calculation is "exact"! It has to be understood that a $1-\alpha$ CI must have *at least* a $1-\alpha$ chance of covering the true parameter, *no matter what the underlying distribution is* (within the assumed family). "Exact" means that the infimum of all these coverages, taken over the entire family of distributions, *equals* $1-\alpha$. To achieve this, the actual coverage *for many of the possible distributions* often must be greater than $1-\alpha$.

Comment: To all - thanks for the comments!  Very insightful and helpful. @cardinal - could you point me in the direction of a reference to help me calculate the "coverage" of the CI in the way that you did?  Thanks

Comment: @Andrew: I pasted the code into onestop's answer so that it would be available. Basically, the idea is that since your random variable is discrete, you know for each unique outcome whether or not the true parameter will be in the CI constructed from that outcome. You also know the probability of each outcome occurring. So, you just sum up the probabilities for the unique outcomes for which the true parameter is inside the CI. :)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You're not going wrong. It simply isn't possible to construct a [confidence interval for a binomial proportion](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_proportion_confidence_interval) which *always* has coverage of *exactly* 95% due to the discrete nature of the outcome. The Clopper-Pearson ('exact') interval is guaranteed to have coverage of *at least* 95%. Other intervals have coverage closer to 95% *on average*, when averaged over the true proportion.

I tend to favour the Jeffreys interval myself, as it has coverage close to 95% on average and (unlike the Wilson score interval) approximately equal coverage in both tails.

With only a small change in the code in the question, we can compute the exact coverage without simulation.

```
p <- 0.3
n <- 1000

# Normal test
CI <- sapply(0:n, function(m) prop.test(m,n)$conf.int[1:2])
caught.you <- which(CI[1,] <= p & p <= CI[2,])
coverage.pr <- sum(dbinom(caught.you - 1, n, p))

# Clopper-Pearson
CI <- sapply(0:n, function(m) binom.test(m,n)$conf.int[1:2])
caught.you.again <- which(CI[1,] <= p & p <= CI[2,])
coverage.cp <- sum(dbinom(caught.you.again - 1, n, p))
```

This yields the following output.

```
> coverage.pr
[1] 0.9508569

> coverage.cp
[1] 0.9546087
```

Comment: "*It simply isn't possible to construct a confidence interval for a binomial proportion which always has coverage of exactly 95% due to the discrete nature of the outcome*" --- aside, perhaps, for the (somewhat odd) possibility of randomized intervals. (At least in that way, it *can* be done, though it may well be that it usually *shouldn't*.)

Comment: @Glen_b I have long been curious about the objections to randomized decisions. I believe Jack Kiefer remarked that if you're ok using randomization to collect your samples, you should have no problem using it in the decision process. If you need a decision procedure that is reproducible, documented, and difficult to cheat with, just generate any random values needed for the randomized interval *before* collecting the data--make it part of the design.